# Syslog cannot start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog, syslogd

I run rsyslog on Ubuntu server.

after rsyslog starts, it restarts in a loop.
here is a piece of /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 13 16:05:50 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Aug 13 16:05:50 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Aug 13 16:05:51 ip-10-92-237-215 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 13 16:05:51 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd"             swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="31895" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 13 16:05:51 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Aug 13 16:05:51 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Aug 13 16:05:52 ip-10-92-237-215 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 13 16:05:52 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="31907" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 13 16:05:52 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Aug 13 16:05:52 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Aug 13 16:05:53 ip-10-92-237-215 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 13 16:05:53 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="31919" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 13 16:05:53 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Aug 13 16:05:53 ip-10-92-237-215 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide `ls -la /var/log/syslog` and `ps aux | grep sys` output

Answer (score 0):

That could be a configuration problem.  Try starting rsyslog in configuration check mode:

```
/path/to/rsyslogd -f/path/to/config-file -N1
```